Approximate the function cos(x) by a polynomial of degree N using linear optimization
I want to find an approximation to the cos(x). I formulated the problem as a linear optimization problem as follows:
$$
\min \sum_{i=1}^{M} e_i 
$$
subject to:
$-(a_0 + a_1x_i + \dots + a_nx_i^{N})-e_i \leq -\cos(x_i)$
and
$a_0 + a_1x_i + \dots + a_nx_i^{N} -e_i\leq \cos(x_i)$.
The points $x_i$ are $M$ points in the interval $[0,1]$. I tried to solve it using Python as follows:
from scipy.optimize import linprog
import numpy as np

def construct_matrix_sup(M, N, a, b, points):

     matrix = np.zeros((M, M + N + 1))

     for i in range(M):
        for j in range(M + N + 1):
           if j == 0:
              matrix[i, j] = -1
           if j >= N + 1:
              matrix[i, j] = -1 if j - (N + 1) == i else 0
           else:
              matrix[i, j] = -1 * points[i] ** j

     return matrix

def construct_matrix_inf(M, N, a, b, points):

     matrix = np.zeros((M, M + N + 1))

     for i in range(M):
         for j in range(M + N + 1):
             if j == 0:
                 matrix[i, j] = 1
             if j >= N + 1:
                 matrix[i, j] = -1 if j - (N + 1) == i else 0
             else:
                 matrix[i, j] = 1 * points[i] ** j

     return matrix

def construir_vetor_c(M, N):

     c = np.zeros(M + N + 1)
     for i in range(M + N + 1):
         if i >= N + 1:
             c[i] = 1
     return c
    

M = 1000
N = 20
a = 0.1
b = 1

points = np.linspace(a, b, M)

A_sup = construct_matrix_sup(M, N, a, b, points)

A_inf = construct_matrix_inf(M, N, a, b, points)

b_sup = -np.cos(points)

b_inf = np.cos(points)

A = np.concatenate((A_sup, A_inf), axis=0)

b = np.concatenate((b_sup, b_inf))

c = construir_vetor_c(M, N)

result = linprog(c,A_ub = A, b_ub=b, method = 'revised simplex')

I devised a function to generate the matrix $A$  and the cost vector $c$  then employed the simplex method to solve the linear programming problem subject to $Ax \leq b$ where $x^{T}=(a_0, \dots, a_N, e_1, \dots, e_M)$. But I'm just finding the coefficient $a_0$ the other ones are zero.
Is there something wrong with my problem formulation or simplex implementation?

You might look up the Remez algorithm.

@m-stgt The objective function and constraints are linear in the decision variables $a_j$ and $e_i$.  The original (unconstrained)  problem is to minimize the (nonlinear) sum of absolute errors, and the formulation given is a standard linearization.

I recommend printing out A, b, and c for a smaller instance to debug.

Look at the default values on the bounds. The default options may be that the variables are non negative. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4787995/simple-linear-programming-problem-with-dual-objective#comment10183342_4787995

I identified the mistake. I was assuming that all decision variables were positive, when in fact both the coefficients and the errors have no constraints. I corrected it and managed to make the approximation.
